# dompdf with Symfony 2.1 project

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, dompdf

How can I make dompdf work with a Symfony 2.1 project?
I followed this [TUTORIAL](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/wiki/Installation) but I'm still getting this exception:

> Notice: Use of undefined constant DOMPDF_LIB_DIR - assumed
>   'DOMPDF_LIB_DIR' in
>   [blablabla]/vendor/dino/dompdf/lib/DOMPDF/stylesheet.cls.php
>   line 16

if not this, what is the best and simplest library to create pdf from html with Symfony 2.1 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I've done to make DOMPDF available to me in a Symfony2 project:

1. require the DinoPDF composer package:
   php composer.phar require dino/dompdf, version 0.1.1 (or dev-master)
2. DomPDF init files need to be required() somewhere in the loading process:

   - copy the vendor/dino/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php.dist to app/dompdf_config.inc.php
   - copy the vendor/dino/dompdf/dompdf_config.custom.inc.php.dist to app/dompdf_config.custom.inc.php
   - add in your app/autoload.php:

     ```
     require_once __DIR__.'/dompdf_config.inc.php';
     ```

dompdf_config.inc.php defines the paths to your DOMpdf installation. DinoPDF distribution changed the paths within the library, so this has to be taken care of:

**DOMPDF_INC_DIR**: Main DOMPdf classes. In dinoPDF distribution of DOMPdf this folder is renamed from dompdf/include to dompdf/lib/DOMPDF

**DOMPDF_LIB_DIR**: Additional resources - fonts, etc. In dinoPDF distribution of DOMPdf this folder is renamed from dompdf/lib to dompdf/lib/vendor

Here are the changes I've introduced to dompdf_config.inc.php:

```
/**
 * The root of your DOMPDF installation
 */
define("DOMPDF_DIR", str_replace(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, '/',                     realpath(__DIR__.'/../vendor/dino/dompdf/')));
/**
 * The location of the DOMPDF include directory
 * Main DOMPdf classes
 * In dinoPDF distribution of DOMPdf this folder is renamed from dompdf/include to     dompdf/lib/DOMPDF
 */
define("DOMPDF_INC_DIR", DOMPDF_DIR . "/lib/DOMPDF");

/**
 * The location of the DOMPDF lib directory
 * Additional resources - fonts, etc.
 * In dinoPDF distribution of DOMPdf this folder is renamed from dompdf/lib to     dompdf/lib/vendor
 */
define("DOMPDF_LIB_DIR", DOMPDF_DIR . "/lib/vendor");

/** Include the custom config file if it exists */
if ( file_exists(__DIR__ . "/dompdf_config.custom.inc.php") ){
    require_once(__DIR__ . "/dompdf_config.custom.inc.php");
}

def("DOMPDF_FONT_DIR", DOMPDF_LIB_DIR . "/fonts/");
```

This should correctly include the library, so that it could be used in controllers, for ex. like this:

```
/**
 * @Route("/export_pdf", name="export_pdf")
 */
public function exportPDFAction($id)
{   
    $html =
    '<html><body>'.
    '<p>Put your html here, or generate it with your favourite '.
    'templating system.</p>'.
    '</body></html>';

    $dompdf = new \DOMPDF();
    $dompdf->load_html($html);
    $dompdf->render();

    $response = new Response();

    $response->setContent($dompdf->output());
    $response->setStatusCode(200);
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');

    return $response;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a much easier way, as dompdf itself now has rudimentary composer support: http://blog.viison.com/post/58696419659/dompdf-symfony2

Sorry for not posting the steps inline here but I've already written the blog post some time ago!

Answer (score 1):

There's actually a must simpler way to include DomPDF in a Symfony2 project.

First, add DomPDF in your `composer.json` file:

```
{   
    "require": {
        // ...
        "dompdf/dompdf": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

After installation, edit the `app/autoload.php` file of your Symfony application and add these lines at the end (before the `return` statement) :

```
// Requirements for DOMPDF
define('DOMPDF_ENABLE_AUTOLOAD', false);
require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/dompdf/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php';
```

And you're done!

But as Slavik mentioned above, there may be better solutions to dompdf, such as the *KnpSnappyBundle* which uses `wkhtmltopdf`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the `dompdf_config.inc.php` file too.

Comment: I don't understand the line 5:

"copy the dompdf_config.*.inc.php.dist files to dompdf_config.*.inc.php to your working directory"

I have:

vendor/dino/dompdf/dompdf_config_custom.inc.php.dist
vendor/dino/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php.dist

what do I have to do next?

Answer (score 0):

There exist other options, for ex.:

**[wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/)** - a console html2pdf conversion tool that is based on WebKit engine, which guarantees standards-compliancy.

**[KnpSnappyBundle](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpSnappyBundle)** - bundle that integrates Symfony2 with wkhtmltopdf